# Regex Issue w/ Single Line XML

Tags: php, regex

I'm creating a word document via XML, the last step in the process is removing any blank lines.  I appear to have a pattern that works when the xml is multiline; however, it's being generated as a single line which is breaking my preg_replace.  Consider the following XML:

> `**<w:p** w:rsidR="009E48E3" w:rsidRPr="008C0DAB" w:rsidRDefault="009E48E3" w:rsidP="004E0AE3"><w:pPr><w:ind w:right="-540"/></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="008C0DAB">**<w:t>text that should be included</w:t>**</w:r>**</w:p><w:p** w:rsidR="009E48E3" w:rsidRPr="008C0DAB" w:rsidRDefault="009E48E3" w:rsidP="004E0AE3"><w:pPr><w:numPr><w:ilvl w:val="1"/> <w:numId w:val="10"/></w:numPr><w:tabs><w:tab w:val="clear" w:pos="1440"/><w:tab w:val="num" w:pos="1080"/></w:tabs><w:ind w:right="-540" w:hanging="720"/><w:rPr><w:noProof/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr><w:noProof/></w:rPr><w:lastRenderedPageBreak/>**<w:t> ; </w:t>**</w:r>**</w:p>**`

*Inserted the asterisk's simply to try and help readability*

Blank lines are always in-between `<w:t></w:t>` tags and contain a period or semi-colon.  Therefore, the first `<w:p>` tag should remain while the second should be removed.

Here is my pattern: `<w:p .*<w:t>[ ]+?(\.|;)[ ]+?<\/w:t>.*?<\/w:p>`

Any help is apprecriated, thank you!

Comment: I think you missed the `?` after the first `.*`.

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried that as well, no luck.  I'm pretty sure I need to make it totally non-greedy, not sure what I'm missing

Comment: Making the first `.*` lazy won't work because, if the first `<w:t>` element is not a blank line, the `.*?` will consume that element and the rest of the XML until the next `<w:t>` element. This will continue until a blank line `<w:t>` element is encountered. The rest of the pattern will then successfully capture that element and the remainder of that elements' parent `<w:p>` tag. The result is that while the blank line elements _are_ captured, all the preceding consecutive non-blank elements are also included in the capture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your pattern is that the first `.*` will read right to the end of the XML and then eventually backtrack to just before the *last* `<w:t>` tag. From there, the rest of the pattern will successfully match the rest of the XML. Result - the entire XML is captured!

The problem with Itchy's pattern is that the lookahead `(?!.*w:p )` says "only if there are no more `<w:p>` tags ahead". In other words the pattern will only match the *last* `<w:p>` element (if it needs to be removed, that is).

All these problems stem from the usage of `.*`. My 2-part motto is, try not to use it unless absolutely necessary. Then, if you find it *is* absolutely necessary to use it, *try harder not to use it* :)

The following pattern will work:

`<w:p [^<]++(?:(?!<w:t>)<[^<]++)++<w:t> *+[\.;] *+<\/w:t>[^<]*+(?:(?!<\/w:p>)<[^<]++)++<\/w:p>`

**Notes:**

1. `.*` was not used at all!
2. The possessive quantifiers `++` and `*+` are not really required but will speed up the regex.
3. The last part may be simplified to `<\/w:t><\/w:r><\/w:p>` if the element always ends like that.

Comment: Worked like a charm Robin, thank you!  This consumed my entire Saturday and my brain for the entire weekend, thank you for putting me out of my misery :)

Answer (score 0):

For this string you provided the following pattern works:

```
<w:p (?!.*w:p ).*?<w:t>[ ]+?(\.|;)[ ]+?<\/w:t>.*?<\/w:p>
```

I've tested it on [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/ErCGJnpbxa).

It uses [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: Thanks Itchy, it seems to be a step in the right direction; however, when I put it into my app I'm still having issues.  If you go to [this example](http://rubular.com/r/FHlVR6gcOX) on Rubular you can see it again finds no matches, but if you put the last `<w:p>` on a new line it will find 1 match, I'm still not sure why.

Comment: I think you can also fix it with negative lookahead. Please have a look at the link I provided. Otherwise you could split your document into pieces of `<w:p`, then remove the empty ones and join it again.